# Why does it fill only first group box?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a test, and in `Form1_Load` I fill up this test with questions and answers. But it shows only first question. What's the matter?

```
int loc = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
    gb.Size = new Size(500, 200);
    gb.Location = new Point(40, loc);
    gb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine;

    Label q_text = new Label(); // текст питання
    q_text.Text = "Питання" + (i + 1);
    q_text.Font = new Font("Aria", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    q_text.Location = new Point(gb.Location.X, gb.Location.Y);
    gb.Controls.Add(q_text);
    int iter = q_text.Location.Y + 30;

    foreach (string key in questions[i].answers.Keys)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
        rb.Text = key;
        rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
        rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
        iter += 30;
        gb.Controls.Add(rb);
    }

    this.Controls.Add(gb);
    loc += 300;
}
```

Comment: I didn't run this test to check, but the only thing that gives me pause is you are testing the Location of `q_text` which is based on the location of `gb`, but gb hasn't been added to a container yet.  Have you stepped through the code to make sure all coordinates make sense?  Nothing stands out as "wrong" in your code.

Comment: One thing that does seem funny is q_text looks like it's being placed incorrectly.  If you want it at the top left, it's location should be `0,0` relative to it's container.

Comment: gb contains q_text and rb's. I can't understand why it's wrong.

Comment: ty, Jaime Torres, it's helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining your code, there are a few possible issues stemming from `q_text`

```
int loc = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
    gb.Size = new Size(500, 200);
    gb.Location = new Point(40, loc);
    gb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aquamarine;

    Label q_text = new Label(); // текст питання
    q_text.Text = "Питання" + (i + 1);
    q_text.Font = new Font("Aria", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    q_text.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    gb.Controls.Add(q_text);
    int iter = q_text.Location.Y + 30;

    foreach (string key in questions[i].answers.Keys)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
        rb.Text = key;
        rb.Size = new Size(120, 25);
        rb.Location = new Point(q_text.Location.X + 10, iter);
        iter += 30;
        gb.Controls.Add(rb);
    }

    this.Controls.Add(gb);
    loc += 300;
}
```

The only changes here are `q_text` getting set to `0,0`.

An additional change I would make however is to adjust hight by `q_text`'s height:

```
int iter = q_text.Location.Y + q_text_Size.Height + 5;
```

Just in case the label was long and wrapped text.